# Three.js | OrbitControls | How to change center?

Tags: three.js

In three.js How to set the center of the camera orbit ? (with OrbitControls)

Egg : I want to use

`camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 100,50,200 )`

and make my camera orbit around this point and not around 0,0,0

How to set ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the center of rotation for `OrbitControls` like so:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.target.set( x, y, z );
```

The `Vector3` `target` is the center of rotation, and the point the camera "looks at".

three.js r.76

Comment: Controls speed are crazy.

 controls.rotateSpeed = 0.1;
 controls.zoomSpeed = 0.5;
 controls.panSpeed = 0.1;

I've to reduce all values, or I've made a mistake ?

Comment: Then make a new post and show your code -- and preferably a live example. But make a serious effort to solve it yourself, first.

Comment: Attempted import error: 'OrbitControls' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').